# How do I enforce that a class implementing an interface or a subclass extending an abstract class must provide a default constructor?

Tags: java, reflection

I have specified an interface (though I can change it to an abstract class if that helps), say `T`. The users of my API will pass me a `Class<? extends T>` on which I will call `newInstance()` (I cannot change that part). How can I ensure that classes that extend `T` have a constructor which takes no parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You can't force any constructor signatures in Java.

You'd better detect the problem at runtime and throw/propagate a `RuntimeException`. That's what the serialization mechanism does, for example.

To go a little further - if possible, drop the reliance on `.newInstance()` and make an annotation `@FactoryMethod` and use it on a `static` method that would be a factory method:

```
public class Foo {

    @FactoryMethod
    public static Foo createFoo() {
       return new Foo();; // or use another constructor, if there is no default?
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in Java.  Since constructors are not inherited, there is no way to force a zero arg constructor to be present unless there are no constructors in the subclass.  If that is the case than the object will get a zero arg constructor by default.  You can utilize the `super` keyword to invoke the parent's constructor